# is there a way to deploy my ML model in python tkinter

Tags: python, machine-learning, tkinter, pycharm, pickle

Is there a way to deploy my machine learning model(which is currently a pickle file) into Pycharm through Tkinter GUI. I have seen methods to deploy models in python but they all have to do with integrating through flask or Django. The gui allows users to input data but I need the input to be passed through the trained model to produce a prediction.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/rikudoayush/Tkinter-Gui-And-ML-) Tutorial can give you some insight into how to use a machine learning model with Tkinter.

Machine Learning model is like any other python package you can [load your model](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/#:~:text=Finalize%20Your%20Model%20with%20pickle,it%20to%20make%20new%20predictions.) anywhere in the code and use it with the native API, without a need for an HTTP request like with Django and Flask